# Can't disable default login page of spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using spring boot 2.5.5 with spring cloud 2020.0.4 and in my gateway I want to apply a filter to check the token(jwt) is valid or not ? and authorize just one path before the first connection.

and even if I enable the web security or (exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class }) or http.httpBasic().disabled().. I'm always  redirected to spring security login page (localhost:9092/login)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityTokenConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityTokenConfig.class);
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((req, rsp, e) -> rsp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED)).and()
                .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(jwtConfig()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)=
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**/auth-api/**")
                .permitAll();

    //  http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/favicon.ico", "/logout").permitAll();

        if (http.cors() != null) {
            logger.info(new StringBuilder("Config").append(http.cors().toString()).toString());
        } else {
            logger.info(" Security Config cors conf is null");
    }
```

Comment: `http.basic()` isn't `http.formLogin`..

Comment: thank you for your response .. what do you porpose ?

Comment: You should disable the form login, you are disabling http basic.

Comment: `http.httpBasic().disable().formLogin().disable()` try this if you want disable both form based login and basic Authentication